# how to handle the online users in websocket

Tags: websocket, playframework-2.0, java-websocket

I have made a chat app over websocket protocol, now my question is how to handle the current online users, should i store their sessions(i.e user details like user_id) in hashMap or some other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any other option besides storing this information as it is (most probably) important for your application. Imagine that you have the requirement to support private messages: you cannot just send the message to all connected clients.

You should come up with some datastructure that holds your connection information. Maybe some map where the key is the session identifier (or the username, or some oder unique identifier) and the value is a pair of the `WebSocket.In` and `WebSocket.out` objects. You can even have two maps (one for the 'in' objects, one for the 'out' objects), whatever suits you. Then you can send a message to a specific client or just to a couple of them but not all.

You can use the `public void onReady(WebSocket.In<String> in, WebSocket.Out<String> out)` method to put the data in the map. (here I assume that you are using Java and handle the WebSockets with callbacks)

Of course, don't forget to clean up the map(s) when the socket is closed (look at the `in.onClose()` method).

Comment: right now i am using a concurrent hashmap to store the user session, i thought there may be some better way to store the sessions like serialize the WebSocket.In,WebSocket.out objects into bytes and save in database for further access.

Comment: by the way.....is it safe to maintain the user's session in ConcurrentHashMap and how many users will be maintained in this ConcurrentHashMap?

Comment: How big this Map would be depends entirely on your application. Of course if you put there really huge amounts of data this will need some memory space. But on the other hand consider the case where you store all this information into a database - can you guarantee that your database is fast enough??? If you consider this further you can always implement some logic where you put part of the information in a database (e.g. users that haven't responded for a long time) and keep the other part in memory.

Comment: i understood thnx, i am just wondering how the xmpp servers (like openfire) store the user sessions, i mean what kind of storage mechanism for the users sessions?